# Removing random items,

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a static page that contains 10 images on the top of the page and 10 paragraps about those images later on the page. I randomly want to show 4 images (which I found the solution for) but I'm unsure how to match those to the text div coming later because I should hide/show the paragraphs about the image

the html:

```
<div id="images">
 <div><img src="img1"></div>
 <div><img src="img2"></div>
 ...
 <div><img src="img10"></div>
</div>
```

and later on the page

```
<div id="text">
 <p>text about image 1</p>
 <p>text about image 2</p>
 ...
 <p>text about image 10</p>
</div>

randomElements = jQuery("#images div").get().sort(function(){ 
 return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5
}).slice(0,4)
```

To show the same paragraphs as the random images I have chosen I guess I should use the `:nth-child()` selector. But I have not been able to find out how to get the child number from the `randomElements`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all images are present in the DOM (and are merely shown/hidden), then I'd suggest:

```
$('#images div:visible').each(
    function(){
        var i = $(this).index()
        $('#text p').eq(i).show();
    });
```

References:

- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
- [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to find the paragraph tag that lines up with the div tag that contains the image.  Create a function that gets six random, unique integers between 1 and 10; remove the div and the paragraph tags with that index with jquery.

Comment: thx for that approach ! Ive tried using index on 'randomElementes' wich just gave me 1,2,3,4 but this should work much better and probably faster

Answer (score 0):

I would rearrange your html if you can. This is much more semantic friendly and your current random selection should still work.

```
<div id="images">
  <div>
    <img src="img1">
    <p>text about image 1</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="img2">
    <p>text about image 2</p>
  </div>
  ...
  <div>
    <img src="img10">
    <p>text about image 10</p>
  </div>
</div>
```